# Inkline breadcrumb :to doesn`t work properly

Tags: css, nuxt.js, breadcrumbs, nuxt-link

I am using inkline breadcrumbs and by docs description I can use :to routing, but it doesn't work properly. :href is working, but I want to use NuxtLink instead of a element. I could add NuxtLink in  but it will generate nested a then.

```
<i-breadcrumb-item
   :to="{ path: /something}">
   Start
</i-breadcrumb-item>
```

https://www.inkline.io/docs/components/breadcrumb

Comment: Shouldn't you have `:to="{ path: '/something' }">`?

Comment: Tried, doesn't work. https://www.inkline.io/docs/components/breadcrumb , so I just recreated all the code from breadcrumbs by hand

Comment: Maybe try with `name` in the object, rather than `path`. Check also your Vue devtools to see if everything is great with your router. Do you maybe have a public repo?